# Unable to prevent Navigation to Next page React Firebase

Tags: reactjs, firebase-authentication

I am creating a web app using firebase and react. My signup function works but I am having some trouble with edge cases such as when a user tries to signup with an email that already exists. How do I prevent navigation to the next page?

```js
async function handleSignup(e) {
        e.preventDefault()
        validatePassword()
        try {
            // setError('')
            setLoading(true)
            await signup(emailRef.current.value, passwordRef.current.value)
            history.push('/profile')
            console.log('created User' + currentUser.uid)
        } catch {
            setError('Failed to Create an Account')
        }
        setLoading(false)
    }
```

```js
function signup(email, password) {
        auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
            .then((cred) => {
                return db.collection('students').doc(cred.user.uid).set()
            })
            .catch((e) => {
                if (e.code === 'auth/email-already-in-use') {
                    console.log('Email already in Use')
                    alert('Email already in use')
                }
                if (e.code === 'auth/weak-password')
                    alert(
                        'Password must be at least 7 characters long and contain special characters'
                    )
            })
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to refactor your async `singup` using [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise).

```
const signup = (email, password) => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
      .then((cred) => {
          return resolve(db.collection('students').doc(cred.user.uid).set())
      })
      .catch((e) => {
          if (e.code === 'auth/email-already-in-use') {
              console.log('Email already in Use')
              return reject('Email already in use')
          }
          if (e.code === 'auth/weak-password')
              return reject('Password must be at least 7 characters long and contain special characters')
      })
});

// and you can use now the try ... catch

try {
  // setError('')
  setLoading(true)
  await signup(emailRef.current.value, passwordRef.current.value)
  history.push('/profile')
  console.log('created User' + currentUser.uid)
} catch(error) {
  setError(error)
}
```

Comment: the problem with this is that, even when signUp is successful it does not naviaget to the next page.

Comment: you can replicate in a codesanbox example ? @StormChaser

Answer (score 0):

An already existing email is not an edge case :)

history.push('/profile') should only be invoked if sign-up is succesfull,
so if signup fails it should throw an error and go to the catch block.
might be worth to check if signup function throws an error as you expect

Comment: It does go to the catch block because the alerts do show up on screen and its logged in the console.

Answer (score 0):

One way of doing so is when you get an error in the `signup` function, you should throw the error so `handleSignup` won't execute the code that comes after `await signup(...)`.

Basically, your goal is to break out of the "success block" in case there's an error. `alert()` will not provide the expected behavior simply because it will not throw anything and that is the reason `history.push` triggers even though your `signup` rejected and the alert showed up.

Instead, it will catch the error and execute `setError(...)`.

Therefore, your `signup` function would look something like this,

```
function signup(email, password) {
  auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
    .then((cred) => {
      return db.collection('students').doc(cred.user.uid).set()
    })
    .catch((e) => {
      if (e.code === 'auth/email-already-in-use') {
        throw new Error(`Email is already in use, ${e}`)
      }
      if (e.code === 'auth/weak-password')
        throw new Error('Password must be at least 7 characters long and contain special characters')
      }
    )}
```

Comment: ok, another q is how do I make my error then more user friendly? I don't exactly want to show the error page if signup fails.

Comment: @StormChaser In this case, you can use an [ErrorBoundary](https://reactjs.org/docs/error-boundaries.html) with a fallback component with whatever you want to display and wrap your signup component with it. [Here's](https://github.com/bvaughn/react-error-boundary) a great library that makes managing the error boundaries much easier.

Comment: ErrorBoundaries are meant to catch unexpected JS errors that will break the whole UI - https://reactjs.org/docs/error-boundaries.html. 

you should use a different apporch to display users a UI message. you could map the error codes you get to a message you would like to display.

Comment: @OmerCohen ErrorBoundaries are also very useful in catching errors of specific components that might throw an unexpected (but taken into consideration) error. This way rather than managing an ErrorBoundary higher in the tree and getting a white screen of death, you can render a very specific fallback component with resetting keys that will replace only the throwing component whilst leaving the UI intact and improving the UX.

Answer (score 0):

Firebase is not allowing you to signup up twice with the same email. I recommend using their error messages.
They also do not allow entering a password under six characters.

Are you looking for a specific solution or a general solution that will fit other systems?.

You can try [my repository](https://blind2k.github.io/emailauthentication/). I worked with the (free) Firebase Auth service and the errors they send back.